# C# - Visual Studio: Get an array of objects from the form (listboxes, Comboboxes, etc) and do 'stuff' with them?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, object, properties

So, here's my code (very simplified):

```
object[] Obj = new object[] {
    ListBoxID,
    CheckBox1
};
string ObjName;
for(int ObjIndex = 0; ObjIndex< Obj.Length; ObjIndex++)
{
    switch (Obj[ObjIndex].GetType().Name)
    {
        #region CheckBox
        case "CheckBox":
            CheckBox ObjType1 = sender as CheckBox;
            ObjName = ObjType1.Name;
```

The code continues, but it just stops right there. If I remove that last line, it is all good, Except I need the name.

This function does a lot of stuff. It is mainly to reset several fields, like, textboxes, checkboxes, listboxes, comboboxes, using it's own name to do so.

I'm self taught with C# and Visual Studio Itself, so I'm not understanding why this isn't working.
I'm assuming that the "object" thing here, is not meant for this sort of work.

Using the 'checkbox' example, this is supposed to do this:

```
            if (!ObjType1.Name.Contains(Globals.PreventResetFrom)) {
                if (ObjType1.Name.Contains(FormName) && (Array.IndexOf(Force, ObjName) >= 0 || (Force.Length == 0 && Array.IndexOf(Skip, ObjName) < 0))) {
                    #region Actions Made
                    ObjType1.Checked = false;
                    #endregion
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Between every type of object, the only thing that changes is what's inside 'Actions Made' Region. The rest is all the same. And, for each Object, of the same type, it's all the same thing.

I'm looking for a way to, instead of having almost 1000 Lines of code, all repeating the same stuff, I'd like to be able to do it this way...

I'm hopping I've explained myself good :)
Keep in mind that all the 'objects' are the actual objects that the user sees, were the user gives a certain input. This is to cancel everything the user has done.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's not clear if you are expecting [`System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx)  or [`System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx). You can't tell just from the class name, since its the same name, `CheckBox`, for both types.

Comment: (read the Answer first for this). `Obj[]` is an `array` of `objects` retrieved from the 'Layout'. It's the same as clicking a `button` and retrieving the "`sender`" as a Button Object. Having that, I guess it would be a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First this: your question is much longer than needed, please keep it short and to the point (a Minimal example is what we like here).

That aside, I think the solution boils down to this:

```
case "CheckBox":
    CheckBox ObjType1 = Obj[ObjIndex] as CheckBox;
```

You are looping over the elements of `Obj`, so it makes no sense to use `sender` in that line.

Comment: Programming... What a wonderful thing! I've copy+pasted a pervious switch loop, and didn't even look at that. Yes, that was the problem! As simple as that :)